# After install PhpStorm get error?

Tags: phpstorm

I installed PhpStorm 2017.3.6 and copy `dvt-jb_licsrv.amd64.exe` file in C:\ drive. I wrote in cmd:

```
dvt-jb_licsrv.amd64.exe -mode install
```

and open task manager `JetBrainsLicServerDVT` change the start.

When I open PhpStorm, I get this error:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPStorm requires a license key to activate, so I don't think this is an error per say. You should have received a trial code before or after you downloaded.

If you have an .edu account or are an active university student, you can get a license that you can renew yearly.